# How to properly add/allow multiple select checkboxes in dropdown in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have a button that shows a dropdown menu in bootstrap 3 with checkboxes next to each item and the user to be able to check multiple without the dropdown menu closing upon clicking each checkbox. How to accomplish this? Also, is there some better way to structure/style so that the checkboxes can show on the left of Item A, Item B, Item C, etc.? (Code below)

```
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Show</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" /> <label><a href="#">Item A</a></label></li>
        <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" /> <label><a href="#">Item B</a></label></li>
        <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" /> <label><a href="#">Item C</a></label></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: With next to "Item A, ..." you mean on the right?

Comment: Checkboxes show up on the left of Item A, Item B, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a little jQuery snippet to avoid the closing behavior:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThC7d/)**

```
$('li').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: I have li's everywhere, this would need to be more specific of a selector if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if, as you mention, you have li's everywhere, set an id for the ul with the class dropdown-menu, for example: `<ul id="dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">`, and then modify the jQuery snippet like this: `$('#dropdown-menu li').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});`